# How important is global choice (a la Lean, HOL Light, Isabelle/HOL) practically?

Tags: classical-logic, axiom-of-choice

Choice is indispensable for much of modern classical mathematics.  Therefore, most proof assistants offer it as part of their standard library.  The most powerful version is sometimes called global choice or Hilbert's choice operator.  This I believe is the version used by Lean, HOL-Light, and Isabelle/HOL, and they use it liberally.  In particular, in Lean it is given by:

```
axiom choice {α : Sort*} : nonempty α → α
```

However, in some ways, global choice is maybe a bit too strong.  It isn't compatible with univalent foundations and it leads to a strange situation where one can define named functions which are not well-defined such as *the function* mapping a vector space to *its basis*.

Instead there are two other forms of choice which are more reasonable, unique choice and the axiom of choice.

By unique choice (UC), I mean the version which is comparable to Lean's choice operator, but requires a unique element to choose from.  I believe it is also called Church's iota operator.

```
axiom unique_choice {α : Sort*} : nonempty α → subsingleton α → α
```

This still allows us to define functions by their properties, as long as we can show only one such function exists.  (In many logics, this follows from other axioms.)

By the Axiom of Choice (AC) I mean something like this:

```
axiom axiom_of_choice : ∀ (A B : Type) (R : A → B → Prop),
  (∀ x : A, ∃ y : B, R x y) -> ∃ f : A → B, (∀ x : A, R x (f x))
```

I may also need to allow `B(x)` to depend on `x : A`.  (Also, this is the version where we assume all types are sets, in the HoTT sense.  More generally, we would restrict `A` to be a set.)

**My question is if it is practical to replace global choice with unique choice and the axiom of choice?**

For example:

1. **Would it be fairly routine to replace global choice in Lean's mathlib, HOL-Light's library, or Isabelle's AFP with the axiom of choice and unique choice?**
2. **Do practitioners in Coq and other systems where they are more careful with axioms find it easy to do modern classical mathematics with just `UC` and `AC`?**

For clarification, my question is not about

- the pure logical strength of global choice:  I don't know the specifics, but I assume there is something that can be proved with global choice and can't with `AC + UC`.  If so, I'm also assuming it isn't particularly mathematically relevant or meaningful.  Of course, if I'm mistaken and there is a theorem commonly used in mathlib, AFP or HOL-Light that doesn't have a simple `AC + UC` provable alternative, I'd love to hear it.
- pedantry:  I might be not stating `UC` or `AC` in exactly the way I need or there may be an extra axiom that is needed to go with `AC + UC` to replace global choice.  If so, I'd love to hear it, but please also assume my question assumes that "correct" formulation as well.  Nonetheless, I'd only like axioms which roughly follow from both `DTT + global-choice` and `DTT + UA + HIT + AC`.  (I say roughly, since the my version of AC assumes that all types are sets, whereas a univalent version would be more careful to specify sets explicitly.)
- constructive math:  I'm not asking about removing all choice, just global choice (and replacing it with `AC + UC`).

---

My motivation for this question is trying to understand how well modern developments of classical formal mathematics can be fit with univalent foundations [as in this question](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/794/what-would-a-fully-classical-and-fully-univalent-itp-and-library-look-like).  The difference between how one states the axiom of choice seems to be one of the largest differences between say Lean and univalent foundations (but obviously not the only one).

Comment: Propositional global choice (i.e. if $A$ is not empty, then $A$ *merely* has an element) isn't incompatible with UA. And personally I think this is the "right one" to compare with the set theoretic GC, in the context of univalent foundations.

Comment: @Trebor, I don't get how what you said is not a tautology.  In base Lean, `nonempty α ↔ (∃ x : α, true)` and `inhabited α → nonempty α`. (Note `nonempty` is a `Prop`).  Do you mean, `(α : Sort*) (β : α -> Sort*) : (∀ x : α, nonempty (β x)) ->  nonempty (Π (x : α), β x)` which is basically formula 3.8.3 in the HoTT book (ignoring set vs type)?   Yes, that might be a cleaner way to state the axiom of choice.

Comment: @Trebor Or do by "propositional global choice" do you just mean `nonempty (nonempty α → α)`.  That would indeed be an interesting axiom.  If so, do you have a citation that this is compatible with UA?

Comment: Yes, that one is equivalent to LEM (but "merely $A$" is crucially not living in `Prop`, because it only concerns propositional equalities, and must not mingle with definitional ones).

Comment: @Trebor Or maybe I even need the Pi binder over types inside the propositional truncation: `nonempty (Π (α : Sort*), nonempty α → α)`. This would just then be the propositional truncation of global choice.  Is this what you meant?  Would this be compatible with UA?  (Again, if sort were replaced with set.)

Comment: @Trebor, Also, I don't understand what you are saying about LEM.  Do you mean the type theoretic LEM `A + (A -> empty)` or propositional LEM `p \/ not p`?  The latter would not be near strong enough.  I still need something strong enough to prove that every vector space has a basis for example.  (Unless propositional LEM and UC is a lot stronger than I realized.)

Comment: It is not true that there is a function `(V : VecSpace) -> BasisOf V` in UA (i.e. from such a function we can deduce false). But with the HoTT axiom of choice it is provable that every vector space merely has a basis.

Comment: I object to the first two sentences :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main practical use of global choice is to be able to make definitions that depend on choice without having to wrap them inside `nonempty`. For example, the definition of algebraic closure in mathlib is currently made up of the following four definitions. I think the advantage of global choice over non-global choice is mainly just a matter of convenience.

```
def algebraic_closure (k : Type u) [field k] : Type u :=
```

```
instance (k : Type u) [field k] : field (algebraic_closure k) :=
```

```
instance (k : Type u) [field k] {R : Type*} [comm_semiring R] [alg : algebra R k] :
  algebra R (algebraic_closure k) :=
```

```
instance (k : Type u) [field k] : is_alg_closure k (algebraic_closure k) :=
```

Your version of choice, `axiom_of_choice` is equivalent another version which I prefer `∀ {ι : Type} {α : ι → Type}, nonempty (Π (i : ι), nonempty (α i) → α i)`.

```
axiom axiom_of_choice : ∀ (A B : Type) (R : A → B → Prop),
  (∀ x : A, ∃ y : B, R x y) -> ∃ f : A → B, (∀ x : A, R x (f x))


example {ι : Type} {α : ι → Type} : nonempty (Π (i : ι), nonempty (α i) → α i) :=
let ⟨f, hf⟩ := axiom_of_choice {i : ι // nonempty (α i)} (sigma α) (λ a b, b.1 = a)
  (λ i, let ⟨i2⟩ := i.2 in ⟨⟨i.1, i2⟩, rfl⟩) in
⟨λ i hi, 
  have h : (f ⟨i, hi⟩).1 = i, from hf ⟨i, hi⟩,
  eq.rec_on h (f ⟨i, hi⟩).2⟩


axiom axiom_of_choice2 {ι : Type} {α : ι → Type} : nonempty (Π (i : ι), nonempty (α i) → α i)

example (A B : Type) (R : A → B → Prop)
  (h : ∀ x : A, ∃ y : B, R x y) : ∃ f : A → B, (∀ x : A, R x (f x)) :=
let ⟨f⟩ := @axiom_of_choice2 A (λ a, {b : B // R a b}) in
⟨λ a, (f a (let ⟨b, hb⟩ := h a in ⟨⟨b, hb⟩⟩)).1, 
 λ a, (f a (let ⟨b, hb⟩ := h a in ⟨⟨b, hb⟩⟩)).2⟩
```

Without global choice I believe it's still possible to prove the mere existence of an algebraic closure. This would be more unpleasant to state however. The definition would look something like this.

```
structure algebraic_closure (K : Type u) [field K] : Type (u+1) :=
( carrier : Type u )
[ i₁ : field carrier ]
[ i₂ : algebra K carrier ]
[ i₃ : is_alg_closure K carrier ]

lemma exists_algebraic_closure {K : Type u} [field K] : 
  nonempty (algebraic_closure K)
```

This would be much less convenient to use, but it wouldn't significantly change the maths that is possible to prove. It is merely a matter of convenience.

A proposal to get around the issue of convenience would be to introduce some sort of special universal quantifier that behaved in a way similar to how universe polymorphism currently works in Lean 3. If we use the notation `∀2` for this quantifier then the axiom of choice would be stated as simply

```
axiom choice : ∀2 {ι : Type}, ∀2 {α : ι → Type}, nonempty (Π (i : ι), nonempty (α i) → α i)
```

`ι` must be a set for this to be consistent with univalence.

The difference between `∀2` and `∀` is that `∀2` should only appear at the beginning of a declaration, and never in the middle of a term. So for example, something like `(∀2 x, B x) -> A` is not allowed. Also, anything containing a `∀2` is not a type. This axiom can be thought of as an axiom schema saying that for any type `α`, the type `nonempty α -> α` is inhabited without saying that the type `∀2{α : Type}, nonempty α -> α` is inhabited.

Any declaration starting with a `∀2` should only be applied to term which do not contain any variables in the context other than those introduced with a `λ2`.

The reason I say this is something like how universe polymorphism works in Lean 3 is that a universe polymorphic definition like `list.length` in some sense quantifies over universe. i.e

```
def list.length {v} {α : Type v} : list α -> nat
```

could be thought of as having some special universe quantifier, `∀u` at the beginning

```
def list.length : ∀u v, ∀ α : Type v, list α -> nat
```

This `∀u` can only appear at the very beginning of a declaration. It is not valid in Lean to have a universe polymorphic hypothesis to a theorem.
`example (h : ∀u v, A : Type v, nat) : nat` is not valid for example.

Using this axiom schema version of choice, it should be possible to prove all theorem schema or definition schema about the algebraic closure in a similar way to how they are currently stated in mathlib.

```
def algebraic_closure : ∀2 (k : Type u) [field k], Type u
```

etc.

This statement of choice should be compatible with univalence because the usual proof of false from global choice is the following. We're assuming `choice : ∀2 (α : Type}, nonempty α → α`. This is implied by (but not equivalent to) the version above `∀2 {ι : Type}, ∀2 {α : ι → Type}, nonempty (Π (i : ι), nonempty (α i) → α i)`, because it is cleaner to prove the contradiction this way.

If `swap` is the path `bool = bool` corresponding to the equivalence that swaps the two elements of `bool` then it is false that

`choice bool _ = cast swap (choice bool _)`

However, using the recursor for equality we can prove this. The motive is will be `λ (A : Type) (h : A = bool), choice A _ = cast h (choice bool)`. This is true when applied to `bool` and `eq.refl _`, but false when applied to `bool` and `swap`.

This proof doesn't work with the `∀2` version of choice however, because in the motive for the induction on equality, we apply choice to a bound variable.

Sorry if this is not the best explanation, I'm not that experienced in explaining type theory in the normal language and presentation. I think about type theory in terms of Lean, not the way it is usually presented in type theory papers.

Comment: I think my proof of why choice is inconsistent with univalence is actually not quite right, but I'm not entirely sure how to fix it. I was a little too informal

Comment: The following gist proves the hard part of the inconsistency between choice and univalence in Lean without using Prop. The proof given in my answer is pretty close to correct. https://gist.github.com/ChrisHughes24/81743833e14005f1b827c89a7e57c5d6

Comment: Nice answer.  I’ve also noticed that `nonempty` is a monad so I think your forall2 is basically doing the usual monad of thing of keeping the global choice function and its derivatives wrapped inside a `nonempty`.  Then like you said, it is more a matter of convince and notation.

Comment: I think the motive should be `λ (A : Type) (h : A = bool), choice (cast h A) _ = cast h (choice Bool) _`.

Comment: @ChristopherHughes Actually, I think your non-global AC is too weak.  I think you want `axiom prop_choice : nonempty (Π {α : Sort*}, nonempty α → α)` instead of the weaker `example {α : Type} : nonempty (nonempty α → α)` that you proved. 
  I think this `prop_choice` is equivalent to the non-global axiom of choice I gave.  I don't know how this changes your answer.

Comment: Your version of choice will also be inconsistent with univalence by more or less the same proof, because `false` is a proposition basically, so if  `(Π (α : Type), nonempty α → α) -> false` it is very straightforward to prove from this that `nonempty (Π (α : Type), nonempty α → α) -> false`.

Comment: You're right that my version is too weak though. I think this is the better version`∀ (ι : Type) (α : ι → Type), nonempty (Π (i : ι), nonempty (α i) → α i` In HoTT I think `ι` would have to be a set.

Comment: I will edit my answer

Comment: `lemma chris_choice_of_jason_choice 
  (jason_choice : ∀ (A B : Type) (R : A → B → Prop),
  (∀ x : A, ∃ y : B, R x y) -> ∃ f : A → B, (∀ x : A, R x (f x))) : 
  ∀ (ι : Type) (α : ι → Type), nonempty (Π (i : ι), nonempty (α i) → α i) :=
λ ι α, let ⟨f, hf⟩ := jason_choice {i : ι // nonempty (α i)} 
  (sigma α) (λ i x, x.1 = i) (λ x, nonempty.cases_on x.2 (λ a, ⟨⟨x, a⟩, rfl⟩)) in 
⟨λ i h, begin have h₁ := (f ⟨i, h⟩).2, rwa hf ⟨i, h⟩ at h₁, end⟩`

Comment: Your Forall2 looks like the [Meinongian encoding](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/#Meinong) of free logic. Free logic and modal logic absolutely have applications towards description operators. I'm not sure how convenient it would be to work this way constructively though.